# How to draw an overlay on a SurfaceView used by Camera on Android?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I have a simple program that draws the preview of the `Camera` into a `SurfaceView`. What I'm trying to do is using the `onPreviewFrame` method, which is invoked each time a new frame is drawn into the `SurfaceView`, in order to execute the `invalidate` method which is supposed to invoke the `onDraw` method. In fact, the `onDraw` method is being invoked, but nothing there is being printed (I guess the camera preview is overwriting the text I'm trying to draw).

This is a simplify version of the `SurfaceView` subclass I have:

```
public class Superficie extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
 SurfaceHolder mHolder;
 public Camera camera;
 Superficie(Context context) {
  super(context);
  mHolder = getHolder();
  mHolder.addCallback(this);
  mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
 }
 public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder) {
  camera = Camera.open();
  try {
   camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
   camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
     invalidar();
    }
   });
  } catch (IOException e) {}
 }
 public void invalidar(){
  invalidate();
 }
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
  Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
  parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
  camera.setParameters(parameters);
  camera.startPreview();
 }
 @Override
 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.draw(canvas);
  // nothing gets drawn :(
  Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
  canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2,
    canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
 }
}
```

Comment: can u pls help me how u have done i m trying to change drawing color on button click like BUTTON1->red button2->yellow  etc how will i do this using canvas ? i want to apply on live camera same as live camera effects work

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`SurfaceView` probably does not work like a regular `View` in this regard.

Instead, do the following:

1. Put your `SurfaceView` inside of a
   `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` in
   your layout XML file, since both of
   those allow stacking of widgets on
   the Z-axis
2. Move your drawing logic
   into a separate custom `View` class
3. Add an instance of the custom View
   class to the layout XML file as a
   child of the `FrameLayout` or
   `RelativeLayout`, but have it appear
   after the `SurfaceView`

This will cause your custom `View` class to appear to float above the `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Thanks so much... that's a nice example and I'm sure that's all I need to do what I want :)

Comment: @CommonsWare So will this answer that you supplied work in a situation where you are trying to overlay one surfaceview on top of another surfaceview? What do you mean by custom View class? The reason that I'm asking is because I'm facing a similar problem located here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548666/overlay-images-onto-camera-preview-surfaceview

Comment: @rohanbk: You cannot overlay two `SurfaceView` widgets, as I understand it. "What do you mean by custom View class?" -- your own subclass of `android.view.View`, or your own subclass of an existing widget class.

Comment: @CommonsWare So, in your honest opinion, would there be any way for me to modify the SurfaceViewOverlay example in the API demos (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/SurfaceViewOverlay.html) so that I can draw bitmap images in a surfaceview on top of a camera surfaceview using the FrameLayout?

Comment: @rohanbk: You do not need a `SurfaceView` to draw bitmap images. For example, `ImageView` does not use a `SurfaceView`, AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm building an Augmented Reality tool, so I need to update the positions of many images (the images are 50x50px png files) on the screen very rapidly. I tried using a View, but it wasn't fast enough. I used a SurfaceView to draw the images, and it worked, but I wasn't able to overlay it onto the camera (since according to you, surfaceview overlaying doesn't work). Will an ImageView be able to quickly render images on the phone screen? Also, thank you for all the help you've given. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @rohanbk: I have no idea how the AR apps do it -- sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for all the other advice though. I've been grappling with a means to overlay a rapidly updating view on top of a live camera feed for a while now.

Comment: @GobiasKoffi : Budy i think u have done with what i want. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749480/how-to-set-just-a-green-camera-view-with-the-l-e-d-light-in-android/7749522#7749522

Comment: @GobiasKoffi : I need your help to implement such camera effect with canvas in android. So Please help me in this. It will be realy appreciate.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer I ended up going with OpenGL-ES. It has a steep learning curve, but it will do what you're trying to do. I haven't touched any Android code in the past year as my academic and professional focus shifted, so good luck with what you're trying to do :)

Comment: You can do it easily using AndEngine and its andengineaugmentedrealityextension. Unfortunately, the extension itself is lesser GPL licensed.

Comment: @CommonsWare Any idea on how to record a video that combines the surface preview and the overlay together?

Comment: @GuyZ: Other than the media projection APIs (to record the entire screen), I do not know how to do this. That's not saying there is no solution, but this is not a problem area that I have investigated.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm talking about a SnapChat like solution. Add a face blur to a recorded video for example...

Comment: @CommonsWare , I want to watermark video with help of ffmpeg , like stickers are added to video, I know how to use ffmpeg, but my problem is to get the position and rotation of sticker on surfaceview any help that you can provide would be useful my question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963522/android-stickers-on-video-using-ffmpeg

Comment: @CommonsWare The link is dead now, please update.

Answer (score 17):

Try calling `setWillNotDraw(false)` from `surfaceCreated`:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        setWillNotDraw(false); 
        mycam.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mycam.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG,"Surface not created");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawRect(area, rectanglePaint);
    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "On Draw Called");
}
```

and calling `invalidate` from `onTouchEvent`:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call the `super.draw()` method first before you do anything in surfaceView's draw method.

Comment: That's exactly what he does in his original code :)