# Display image on Camera perview?

Tags: java, android, camera

Is it possible to display an image in the background of the camera preview? The image be 80% transparent, so don't worry about not seeing the preview. I want to be able to see both the camera preview and the transparent image. I believe this falls into the augmented reality category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer is relevant to your interests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android/2934759#2934759) also [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0d8587b4b2139a85/6e1f453ac051f6bd?#6e1f453ac051f6bd)