# How to draw on top of camera preview?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas

I want to draw some thing on the view which we get when our camera is on in android mobile.

I do not want to take picture nor record video just that view from camera and then draw some thing on screen.

Drawing on screen will not be and issue but when we turn on camera which view we get and how can we use that view in our application?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to check [androids camera-API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).

You can get the preview to display in a [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) or your own View-subclass, which can then be used to draw on. Some more knowledge might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RelativeLayout to put other views aligned with the surfaceView used for camera preview