# How to draw circle,rectangle manually on android videoplayer

Tags: android

I just wanna draw circle,rectangle or something manually on video player(while video playing) in android.Is it possible?If any code samples are much better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is already an answer to ur question:

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android)

**Quoted from the post:**

> `SurfaceView` probably does not work like a regular `View` in this
>   regard.
>
> Instead, do the following:
>
> 1. Put your `SurfaceView` inside of a
>      `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` in
>      your layout XML file, since both of
>      those allow stacking of widgets on
>      the Z-axis
> 2. Move your drawing logic
>      into a separate custom `View` class
> 3. Add an instance of the custom View
>      class to the layout XML file as a
>      child of the `FrameLayout` or
>      `RelativeLayout`, but have it appear
>      after the `SurfaceView`
>
> This will cause your custom `View` class to appear to float above the
>   `SurfaceView`.

There is also a sample project to your need

[See here](https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry/)