# Drawing over my own custom View

Tags: android

I've created my own View (in which I draw on Canvas), and I want to make another Layer (with buttons etc.) on top of it. How can I do this?

Comment: make the empty/non-drawing area of the upper layer as transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a FrameLayout and add the views you want there - the FrameLayout allows for Overlaying of controls.

Just be sure that the top one has some opacity set, otherwise you won't see the controls below it - also be careful of the order you add the Views.

```
FrameLayout layers = new FrameLayout(this);
CustomViewBottom bottom = new CustomViewBottom(this);
CustomViewOverlay overlay = new CustomViewOverlay(this);
//the overlay class must set the ALPHA property 
//of the PAINT object that it uses to draw

layers.addView(bottom);
layers.addView(overlay);
this.setContentView(layers);
```

[How to draw an overlay on a SurfaceView used by Camera on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android)