# setPreviewDisplay and setDisplayOrientation

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm puzzled by OpenCV's Android camera sample code.  They make a custom class which implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and put the following line inside the method `surfaceChanged`:

```
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
```

The Android documentation for `setPreviewDisplay` explains:

> This method must be called before startPreview(). The one exception is
>   that if the preview surface is not set (or set to null) before
>   startPreview() is called, then this method may be called once with a
>   non-null parameter to set the preview surface. (This allows camera
>   setup and surface creation to happen in parallel, saving time.) The
>   preview surface may not otherwise change while preview is running.

Unusually, OpenCV's code never calls `setPreviewDisplay` with a non-null SurfaceHolder.  It works fine, but changing the rotation of the image using `setDisplayOrientation` doesn't work.  This line also doesn't appear to do anything, since I get the same results without it.

If I call `setPreviewDisplay` with the SurfaceHolder supplied to `surfaceChanged` instead of `null`, the image rotates but does not include the results of the image processing.  I also get an `IllegalArgumentException` when calling `lockCanvas` later on.

What's going on?

Here are the (possibly) most relevant parts of their code, slightly simplified and with methods inlined.  Here is [the full version](http://codepad.org/p9O3JcNK).

**Class definition**

```
public abstract class SampleViewBase extends SurfaceView 
    implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {
```

**When the camera is opened**

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        synchronized (SampleViewBase.this) {
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, mFrame, 0, data.length);
            SampleViewBase.this.notify(); 
        }
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
    }
});
```

**When the surface changes**

```
/* Now allocate the buffer */
mBuffer = new byte[size];
/* The buffer where the current frame will be copied */
mFrame = new byte [size];
mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);

try {
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "mCamera.setPreviewDisplay/setPreviewTexture fails: " + e);
}

[...]

/* Now we can start a preview */
mCamera.startPreview();
```

**The run method**

```
public void run() {
    mThreadRun = true;
    Log.i(TAG, "Starting processing thread");
    while (mThreadRun) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;

        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                this.wait();
                bmp = processFrame(mFrame);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (bmp != null) {
            Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (canvas.getWidth() - getFrameWidth()) / 2, 
                    (canvas.getHeight() - getFrameHeight()) / 2, null);
                mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Finishing processing thread");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the rotation issue using OpenCV itself: after finding out how much the screen rotation needs to be corrected using [this code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29), I apply a rotation matrix to the raw camera image (after converting from YUV to RGB):

```
Point center = new Point(mFrameWidth/2, mFrameHeight/2);
Mat rotationMatrix = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, totalRotation, 1);
```

[...]

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuv, mIntermediate, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGBA, 4);
Imgproc.warpAffine(mIntermediate, mRgba, rotationMatrix, 
    new Size(mFrameHeight, mFrameWidth));
```

A separate issue is that `setPreviewDisplay(null)` gives a blank screen on some phones.  The solution, which I got from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-opencv/KVqUzyF8e3A) and draws on [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20999#c8) bugreport and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android) SO question, passes a hidden, "fake" SurfaceView to the preview display to get it to start, but actually displays the output on an overlaid custom view, which I call CameraView.  So, after calling `setContentView()` in the activity's `onCreate()`, stick in this code:

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    final SurfaceView fakeView = new SurfaceView(this);
    fakeView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    fakeView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);

    final CameraView cameraView = (CameraView) this.findViewById(R.id.cameraview); 
    cameraView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true); 
    cameraView.fakeView = fakeView;
}
```

Then, when setting the preview display, use this code:

```
try {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10));
    else
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(fakeView.getHolder());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "mCamera.setPreviewDisplay fails: "+ e);
}
```

If you are only developing for Honeycomb and above, just replace setPreviewDisplay(null) with `mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10));` and be done with it.  `setDisplayOrientation()` still doesn't work if you do this, though, so you'll still have to use the rotation matrix solution.

Comment: Hi, even I was looking for the same solution. It would be great if you could share the sample

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same problem. Instead of using a `SurfaceView.Callback`, I subclassed their class `JavaCameraView`. See my live face detection and drawing sample [here](https://github.com/charlesmunger/OpenCVDemo/blob/master/src/edu/ucsb/ece251/charlesmunger/cvdemo/FaceMaskView.java). It was then trivial to rotate the matrix coming out of the camera according to the device's orientation, prior to processing. Relevant excerpt of linked code:

```
@Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
        int flipFlags = 1;
        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            flipFlags = -1;
            Log.i(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Orientation is" + getRotation());
        }
        Core.flip(inputFrame, mRgba, flipFlags);
        inputFrame.release();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
        if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
            int height = mGray.rows();
            if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
                mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't have `org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener` or
`org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView` available as imports - the relevant Java files just aren't there.  How did you configure this?

Comment: Do you have the OpenCV SDK as an android dependency? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#import-opencv-library-and-samples-to-the-eclipse

Comment: Yes, and I can use all the other OpenCV classes.

Comment: Get the libary from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.4/OpenCV-2.4.4-android-sdk.zip/download

Extract it, and open the "OpenCV Library 2.4.4" project in eclipse.

Comment: Ah, turns out I was using an older version.  I'm noticing that you don't correct for rotation in your code, only for the flipped image on front-facing cameras.  Does OpenCV automatically rotate the image to the correct orientation?

Comment: Yes. By default the view is rendered with the correct orientation, but the camera returns the same pixels regardless. This is why you rotate the image *before* you process it, not after.

Comment: Actually, to amend my previous comment: No, it doesn't. My app only needed to work in landscape.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it to work in all orientations.  Do you think there's some way I could make this work, or should I try something else?

Comment: Yes - Just switch on display.getRotation and compare it to all four possible values instead of doing a simple if on one of them.

Comment: It's not enough to just flip the screen to go from portrait to landscape: I'd have to rotate the image.  That's the problem that brought me here.

Comment: Rotating an image 90 degrees can be done by the Core.transpose(Mat src, Mat dst) function.

Comment: Transposing a matrix flips it along the diagonal.  To rotate the matrix, I need to use `warpAffine` with a rotation matrix from `getRotationMatrix2d`.  However, I can do this with my existing code.  I've upvoted your answer since it's quite generally useful, but it doesn't solve my specific problem.