# Can't draw canvas into android bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

Hi guys I'm struggling with bitmaps and canvas. What I'm trying to do is to take a photo with the camera and then allow the user to create two rectangles (by sliding the finger) and mark them in the image (the rectangles should be marked until a button is pressed, the photo is not saved, it is always on memory). So based in a camera example I've made a layout with a SurfaceView to contain the camera preview, and then I've added the code to draw the rectangles in the onPictureTaken method. I've searched some examples about how to implement it but of course is not working. So far, I have this code (inside of onPictureTaken):

```
        final Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0,
                arg0.length);
        surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                switch (arg1.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (source coordinates of rect1 are not set) {
                        setSourceCoordinatesForRect1FromArg1();
                    } else {
                        setSourceCoordinatesForRect2FromArg1();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (end coordinates of rect1 are not set) {
                        setEndCoordinatesForRect1FromArg1();
                    } else {
                        setEndCoordinatesForRect2FromArg1();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                if (coordinates for rect1 are set) {
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPicture.getWidth(), bitmapPicture.getHeight(), bitmapPicture.getConfig());
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
                    canvas.drawRect(/*all of my source coordinates*/, paint);
                } else {
                    if (coordinates for rect2 are set) {
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPicture.getWidth(), bitmapPicture.getHeight(), bitmapPicture.getConfig());
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
                        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
                        canvas.drawRect(/*all of my end coordinates*/, paint);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I don't have any exception, but the rectangles are not drawn, so I'll really appreciate if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. Also, for my particular scenario, would be suitable to use GestureDetector instead of create a custom OnTouchListener?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a long time I could draw into a bitmap. It happened that I've had a couple of errors: first, I was trying to draw in the SurfaceView, which is not possible, and second I've added an ImageView to contain the bitmap and the canvas, so, now my code looks like this:

```
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bt, bt.getWidth(), bt.getHeight(), true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1, paint);//up
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y2, paint);//left
canvas.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2, paint);//down
canvas.drawLine(x2, y1, x2, y2, paint);

ImageView iView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewPreview);
iView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
iView.draw(canvas);
```

This code is in a separate activity, in which I implemented an `OnTouchListener` in order to read the coordinates for drawing the rectangle. After reading the coordinates the code is executed.
For reference, the layout is a FrameLayout that contains an ImageView (take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android/2934759#2934759) answer).
This code is finally drawing a rectangle but lucky me the image is getting bigger :(, but that's another question, so if you want to follow it [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825819/bitmap-scaled-after-drawing-with-canvas).

Answer (score 0):

You create the canvases and bitmaps, but you never connect them to your view:

```
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPicture.getWidth(), bitmapPicture.getHeight(), bitmapPicture.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
canvas.drawRect(/*all of my end coordinates*/, paint);
```

You need to create one bitmap (you did that up top), then draw both rects on there, then connect that bitmap to your view:

```
if (coordinates for rect1 are set) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapPicture);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(/*all of my source coordinates*/, paint);
    } else {
        if (coordinates for rect2 are set) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapPicture);
            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            canvas.drawRect(/*all of my end coordinates*/, paint);
        }
    }
}
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapPicture));
```

Comment: Hi @HaIR, thank you for your answer but it didn't worked: I think you're right regarding the unconnected bitmap and canvas, but when I run the app I have an exception "IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor" when I execute "new Canvas(bitmapPicture);" (I read once that I shouldn't use the original bitmap).

Comment: That would make sense.  DId you try making a new bitmap and attaching it view setImageView to an imageView?  Either way, you need it connected to your view hierarchy and not just floating in limbo.

Comment: Yes @HaIR, I tried setting the bitmap associated to the canvas to an ImageView but nothing happened. About this point I have a question, in my first implementation I only had a SurfaceView, but now because of your answer I've added an ImageView, is that correct (I mean have the SurfaceView and the ImageView in the same layout) or the ImageView should be used instead of the SurfaceView, or maybe it should be in another layout?

Comment: If you have two views, make sure that they are both in your layout (either setup in the layout xml, or added in your code) and that the top one has a clear color background.