# Bitmap scaled after drawing with canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-canvas

I'm trying to take a camera's preview and draw a rectangle over it (I get its coordinates when the user selects an area) but when I show the photo in an ImageView it gets scaled (bigger size). Going to the detail:
1_ My main layout is a LinearLayout which contains a FrameLayout which in turn will contain the camera preview
2_ In my activity I have an instance of `android.hardware.Camera` and I've associated it a `PictureCallback` instance and implemented the `onPictureTaken` method to get the bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inPurgeable = true;            
        opts.inInputShareable = true;
        opts.inScaled = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);
```

3_After taking the photo the user selects an area and I take those coordinates for drawing the rectangle:

```
preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(mCameraPreview);//mCameraPreview is an instance of "CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback"
preview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
    /* read the coordinates x1, y1, x2, y2 */

    //the commented code was already tested, same result        
    //Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y2, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(x2, y1, x2, y2, paint);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(CameraActivity.this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
    //the commented code was already tested, same result    
    //imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap)); 
    imageView.draw(canvas);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(tempBitmap.getWidth(), tempBitmap.getHeight());
    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    preview.addView(imageView);
    }
}
```

The final result is that the rectangle is drawn, but the bitmap is much bigger than the original, do you know why?
Thanks in advance.
PS: I tried bitmap.getWidth()/2 when building the tempBitmap and the image was almost the original size, but the rectangle also shrink.

EDIT: I already tried with `imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true)` and `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)` (also with ScaleType.CENTER, CENTER_CROP, FIT_XY and MATRIX). Does anybody know what is hapenning???

Answer (score 0):

By default image view apply scale on bitmap to fit the bitmap into the whole area of the imageview;

Try this code

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(CameraActivity.this);
imageView .setImageMatrix (new Matrix());
imageView .setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
imageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
```

and remove this line from your code

```
imageView.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: Hi @Swarnendu thanks for your response, but the app still shows the scaled bitmap; I didn't know that the image view apply scale on bitmap, I'll try to follow that clue in order to solve my problem. Thanks again