# Make a scope app in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to make a scope app for android that allows you use the rear camera for the android app as a scope, is this possible, I want to add lines to the app as well that will help aim.  This is an app for a neft gun.  Is this possible, if so can someone give me references/links or explanations on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SurfaceView to display the camera data, and then draw the scope into a transparent view on top of the surface view.

See the [Preview](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html) example from android.com for an example on how to display camera data in a SurfaceView.

Comment: See this answer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android