# Displaying text on Google Glass preview app

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Ok so I have been researching this for a while to no avail.

I am creating a google glass app that will look at a building and tell you the distance from that building. I have the coordinates of the building hardcoded and I now need to display the distance (text variable) to the camera preview.

I have looked at other examples of "overlaying text on the camera preview" that pertain to Android, but nothing that pertains to Google Glass. So can someone explain how to overlay a text box on the camera preview?

Comment: If you have `coordinates` of your `current location` and `coordinates` of the building, then there are a lot of distance calculation strategies, scripts, etc out there, just google it. For drawing on `camera view` search about `augmented reality`

Comment: What about simply adding a `TextView` over the `TextureView` of the Camera preview?

Comment: @SimonMarquis advice looks good. Here's another [SO post on SurfaceView overlays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android) that may help you.