# How to water mark camera with an image?

Tags: android, camera, watermark

I'd like to know how do i water mark the camera while taking a picture. I wanna put a image already taken to be like a map to the person who's taking the new picture. I'm using android studio to do it.
Like this: I'm gonna take a picture, before I take the picture I can see a water mark of a image that I have, and I can positionate the camera to be close to that water mark image and then I take the picture. It's like the water mark image were a mdoel to the photo.

Comment: If you use Camera Intent, you will need write access to the picture file that corresponds to `onActivityResult()`. WIth custom camera app, you receive the image (normally, as a JPEG byte[]) in [Camera.PictureCallback](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html) and you can manipulate this image to your liking.

Comment: I want to water mark the preview of the camera, not the image. But tks for the help.

Comment: Your edit makes the question more clear. You can overlay a view on top of the camera preview. The easiest is to show the "watermark" as a semi-transparent ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually idk how to watermark the camera but may be the following code will help you

```
applyWaterMarkEffect(src, "Water mark text", 200, 200, Color.GREEN, 80, 24, false)


public Bitmap applyWaterMarkEffect(Bitmap src, String watermark, int x, int y, int color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
        paint.setTextSize(size);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
        canvas.drawText(watermark, x, y, paint);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This is not what I was looking for but your answer helped me to find the right one in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android and then I used your code to get what I was looking for. So, Thanks.