# android - Drawing on the same surface as the camera priview

Tags: android, surfaceview

My problem is simple - I have one class that extends `SurfaceView`. I already made some rendering code and tested it. I render on `SurfaceView` in another thread using `holder.lockCanvas(null)` surrounded by `try{...rendering code...}finally{if(canvas!=null)holder.unlockCanvasAndPost();}`

But when I connected the camera I saw tons of "exception locking canvas" messages. It seems that camera locks `SurfaceView` when preview started, and unlocks when it stopped.

This is my problem, please help

Comment: create an overlay view on top of your preview and draw there

Comment: @pskink I have `SurfaceView` as an activity content view and If it possible to render on the same `SurfaceView` as the camera - it will improve the performance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2934759/2252830

Comment: @pskink So, you telling me that it is not possible ?

Comment: did you try the same with a TextureView?

Comment: No, actually, I dont even know what it is. Go to google this now, thanks.

Comment: Opened android developer site, texture view class `It is important to note that only one producer can use the TextureView. For instance, if you use a TextureView to display the camera preview, you cannot use lockCanvas() to draw onto the TextureView at the same time.` Sad.